# Drupal 7: URL alias is getting ignored on pages when "provide a menu link" is unchecked on multilingual site

Tags: url, drupal-7, alias, multilingual

I'm hoping someone can help me because this is driving me crazy.

I have a multilingual DrupaL 7 site set up with English being the main language and French being the secondary language. I have url aliasing set up and for the most part it works correctly.

The problem arises when I have pages that I don't want included in a menu, so I leave the "provide a menu link" box unchecked. Even if the "Generate automatic URL aliases" box is checked for those pages without a menu link, the page completely ignore any url alias patterns I have set up and the url always shows up as 'node/31' instead of 'my-content-page'. If I hardcode in a URL alias via the URL path settings on the page, it WILL take those, but this is not what I want. I want it to take the url alias pattern I've set up for it. I even installed the "Pathauto persistent state" module and forced the "Generate automatic URL aliases" to remain checked just in case, but my alias patters are still ignored.

Both English and French pages do this if the page is not provided a menu link.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? Does anyone have any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have tokens in your URL alias pattern that doesn't work for any reason. In your case it sounds like you have a pattern including a "menu item" token, so when you save your node without a menu item, the URL alias is not created.

The solution would be to either include a menu item, manually add your URL alias, or change anything looking like `[node:menu-link]` in your URL alias patterns to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem, and the point was that the "Basic Page" content-type needed to have available the menus of the appropiate languages in its "menu settings" (in admin/structure/ then "edit" basic-page) .

Hope this will work for you too.

Comment: admin/structure what? admin/structure/menus

Answer (score 0):

If your have a non english site, follow the issue: https://drupal.org/node/1847444 and patch or solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it, "I hope forever", by reading the comment written by enzipher:

> This can happen when you have tokens in your URL alias pattern that
>   doesn't work for any reason.

I'm using a custom pattern and I solved it by following these steps:

1. I went to pattern page, deleted custom token and save
2. I went to node and edit, then saved the node and url alias had been created like domain/language/title_node
3. I went to pattern page, insert same custom token and saved
4. I went to node again and edited it, then saved and the correct node url alias has been created
   domain/language/custom_token_content/title_node

Comment: **It's possible to skip this intensive process by bulk updating nodes** instead of manually updating each one. This can be done via /admin/content, select the nodes and choose "update url alias" in update options. This will update the aliases following the patterns in configuration > search > URL aliases.